# Appium Screenshot with filename

Tags: python-3.x, png, appium-android, takesscreenshot

I am trying to add activity and timestamp on PNG filename, but png file doesn't create in my folder that I selected.

```
import unittest
from time import sleep, strftime
from appium import webdriver

class SettingsTest(uniitest.Testcase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_cap = {}
        ...
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_cap)
    def test_settings(self):
        ts = strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
        activity_name = self.driver.current_activity
        filename = activity_name + '_' + ts

        el = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("Network & internet")')
        el.click()
        self.driver.save_screenshot("/Users/johnd/PycharmProjects/Python/appium_JH_Project/screenshot/"+ filename + '.png')
        sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SettingsTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to a more expressionable title. Which steps have you tried to fix this problem? Have you checked file permissions or alike?

Comment: If you see the self.driver.save_screenshot("folder location"+ filename + ".png"), which I am trying to set to create png screenshot file, but it wasn't create at all.